# Take column of string data in pandas dataframe and split into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe from data I read from a CSV. One column is for the name of a group, while the other column contains a string (that looks like a list), like the following:

```
Group      |  Followers
------------------------------------------
biebers    |  u'user1', u'user2', u'user3'
catladies  |  u'user4', u'user5'
bkworms    |  u'user6', u'user7'
```

I'd like to try to split up the strings in the "Followers" column and make a separate dataframe where each row is for a user, as well as a column showing which group they're in. So for this example I'd like to get the following:

```
User       |     Group
--------------------------------
user1      |     biebers
user2      |     biebers
user3      |     biebers
user4      |     catladies
user5      |     catladies
user6      |     bkworms
user7      |     bkworms
```

Anyone have suggestions for the best way to approach this? Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean a "string that looks like a list?" Does it look like a list of multiple unicode strings? How did that get in there?

Comment: Yes the entries are all strings (that happen to look like a list of unicode strings). The data was read from a CSV, which returned strings for all the entries...

Comment: can you post the result of df.head(10)

Comment: Ok-I attached a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.Followers = df.Followers.str.replace(r"u'([^']*)'", r'\1')

df.set_index('Group').Followers.str.split(r',\s*', expand=True) \
  .stack().rename('User').reset_index('Group').set_index('User')
```

[image]

---

To keep `User` as a column.

```
df.Followers = df.Followers.str.replace(r"u'([^']*)'", r'\1')

df.set_index('Group').Followers.str.split(r',\s*', expand=True) \
  .stack().rename('User').reset_index('Group') \
  .reset_index(drop=True)[['User', 'Group']]
```

Comment: Oh wow, never knew about `expand=True` that will come in handy.

Comment: That was great! I'm wondering though how to make the df so the users are not the index, but just another column... Sorry, I wasn't clear on the exact output I needed...

Comment: @Imu easy, that was a choice of mine.  I'll update my post.

Comment: For the second option I get a: KeyError: ('User', 'Group'). Any idea what might be going on there?

Comment: @Imu fixed typo